# How do i convert the input into an int?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried using int() to convert the input into int, but I just get a TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'. How do i solve this?

```
import random

number = random.randint(1, 50)
lives = 10

guess = int(print("Enter a number between 1 and 50: "))


while guess != number and lives != 0:
    if guess > number:
        guess = int(print("Your guess is higher than the secret number. Enter another guess: "))
        lives -= 1
    else:
        guess = int(print("Your guess is lower than the secret number. Enter another guess: "))
        lives -= 1

if guess == number:
    print("You win!")
else:
    print("You lose!")
```

Comment: `print()` will just output a value but not take user input. Use `input()` instead

Comment: `int(input('Say something'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't `print()` just show some text?

Try using:

```
guess = int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 50: "))
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/taking-input-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to cast the output of `print()` to `int` when, as the error message suggests, `print()` outputs `None`.

If you replace the line 6 "`print`" with "`input`" your code will work (as seems expected) with python 3.

Answer (score 0):

`guess = int(print("Enter a number between 1 and 50: "))` is wrong.
it should be

```
guess = int(input('enter a number between 1 and 50: '))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
guess = int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 50: "))
```

By default input takes everything as a string. And we convert the type afterwards.